# Hide Bottom Tab Bar on some view

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to open one Contentview with NavigationLink.

But I dont get how to hide bottom tab bar when some view gets appear. I tried looking for code everywhere. but couldn't find anything helpful.

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetail(item: item)){
}
```

that is how i open new view

Comment: It is not enough code provided, but I assume you have NavigationView inside TabView, but try to put instead TabView inside NavigationView

Answer (score 0):

This is to little code, but assuming you have a TabView and inside one of the TabView elements you have an NavigationLink, then you can hide the TabView for a specific view by adding the `.navigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool)` modifier.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3338624-navigationbarhidden

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("NavigationLinkView")){
                    Text("NavigationLink")
                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("First View")
                }.tag(0)

                Text("Second View")
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Second View")
                }.tag(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```